# debounceTime() and waiting for events

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I would like to accomplish something in RxJS that I would express in English like this:

> Wait for an event to be raised from a stream, perform some function, then wait for five seconds of silence from this stream, then perform another function.

I have had several attempts at this. The stream I want to subscribe to looks like this:

```
this.documentClick$ = Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('body'), 'mousemove')
    .merge(Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('body'), 'click'));
```

The current two contenders do the job, but each has its faults:

```
this.documentClick$
    .subscribe( () => {
        this.toolbarsVisible = 'visible';
    });

this.documentClick$
    .debounceTime(5000)
    .subscribe( () => {
        this.toolbarsVisible = 'hidden';
    });
```

and

```
this.documentClick$
    .do( () => {
        this.toolbarsVisible = 'visible';
    })
    .debounceTime(3000)
    .subscribe( () => {
        this.toolbarsVisible = 'hidden';
    });
```

What would be the "most correct" way of doing this? I thought using a Subject would be best, but I couldn't get `Observable.fromEvent()` into the Subject.

(I guess the question I really want to ask is: how do I create a Subject from an Observable?)

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn an Observable in a Subject (only from Subject to Observable using `asObservable()` operator).

Obviously I don't know what is you use-case where you want to use Subject but you can take the Observable from `Observable.fromEvent()` and subscribe a Subject to it. Then this Subject will reemit all values from the Observable while still being a Subject where you can call `next()` or whatever.

A simple demo that illustrates such situation:

```
let subject = new Subject();
subject.subscribe(val => console.log('subject', val));

Observable.interval(250)
    .subscribe(subject);

Observable.interval(1000)
    .subscribe(val => subject.next('Hello ' + val));
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/zejata/edit?js,console

This outputs for example:

```
subject 0
subject 1
subject 2
subject Hello 0
subject 3
subject 4
subject 5
subject 6
subject Hello 1
subject 7
subject 8
```